# OpenCV3 undefined reference to cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)

Tags: opencv, cmake, opencv3.0

I just built OpenCV3 and it went very smoothly. I made a small example executable and it built and linked against the new OpenCV3 fine. I then switched my real code base to point to the new OpenCV3, but I am getting some strange linker errors like

```
undefined reference to cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)
```

I am using CMake to find OpenCV with

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(WriteImage WriteImage.cpp)
target_link_libraries(WriteImage ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

and I have inspected those variables and they seem to be set correctly. I have also started from a fresh build tree to make sure CMake hadn't saved anything from when it was linking to OpenCV2. Does anyone know what would cause this problem linking?

The linker says that the problem is in this function:

```
double GetMaxValue(cv::Mat& image)
{
    //Initialize m
    double minVal;
    double maxVal;
    cv::Point minLoc;
    cv::Point maxLoc;

    minMaxLoc(image, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc );

    return maxVal;
}
```

Comment: Without the code that triggered the error, no idea.

Comment: I added the function, but that exact function links fine in my stand alone test project, so it seems like it should be a project configuration problem rather than a problem in the code?

Comment: imho, even with opencv3, it is still: `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`

Comment: I have tried that - it doesn't seem to change anything. At the end of the day these are linked to, so I'm not sure what else it would need?: opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_hal;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d

Comment: cv::_InputArray should be covered by opencv_core

Comment: Have you added the new openCV to the path in the environment variables?

Comment: @AlexanderLeonVI yes, it is on my path: OpenCV_DIR is /home/doria/build/opencv3

Comment: What error message is given?

Comment: undefined reference to cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&) and undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though something was getting added to my include path that I guess was first finding headers that were incompatible with the libraries (that were correctly found). So even though OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS was correct, the final include path had something before its contents.